# How to apply two different mock.patches to one unit test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

When I'm trying to run this test:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)
@mock.patch('requests.post', side_effect=mocked_requests_post)
def test_zeros(self, response):
    self.assertEqual(0, 0)
```

it says `TypeError: test_zeros() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. So, how can I mock two different methods (I need `requests.get` and `requests.post`) in one test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mocks defined in decorators are passed to the decorated function. I don't know what `response` is supposed to be but you need to accept an argument for the get and post objects.

```
@mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)
@mock.patch('requests.post', side_effect=mocked_requests_post)
def test_zeros(self, post_mock, get_mock):
    self.assertEqual(0, 0)
```